# Invalid classpath publish/ export dependency /ouat-contract. Project entries not supported

Tags: gradle, gradle-eclipse

I am trying create an Gradle multi project similar to this structure

```
ouat-services
  - ouat-contract
  - ouat-servicesImpl (web project)
```

I followed the eclipse example and define my ouat-services settings.gradle as

```
include "ouat-contract", "ouat-servicesImpl"
```

In my ouat-servicesImpl build-gradle I define

```
dependencies {
  compile project(':ouat-contract')
}
```

My problem starts when I try apply war plug-in in ouat-servicesImpl, I receive the following message in eclipse problem view:

```
Invalid classpath publish/ export dependency /ouat-contract. Project entries not supported
```

My ouat-services build.gradle

```
configure(subprojects) {

  apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse'
  apply plugin: 'java'

  version = '1.0'

  sourceCompatibility = 1.8
  targetCompatibility = 1.8

  def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
  [compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = defaultEncoding

  repositories {

    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
  }

  jar {
    manifest.attributes provider: 'Company'
  }
}

configure(project(':ouat-servicesImpl')) {

  apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
  apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
  apply plugin: 'findbugs'
  apply plugin: 'jacoco'
  //apply plugin: 'jetty'
  apply plugin: 'pmd'
  apply plugin: 'war'
}

buildscript {

  repositories {

    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.10.1'
  }
}
```

My ouat-servicesImpl build gradle was changed to:

```
dependencies {

  compile project(':ouat-contract')

  cxfArtifacts.each { artifact ->
    compile "org.apache.cxf:$artifact:$cxfVersion"
  }

  springArtifacts.each { artifact ->
    compile "org.springframework:$artifact:$springVersion"
  }

  testCompile "org.testng:testng:$testNGVersion"
  testCompile "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:$hamcrestVersion"
  testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"

  //WAR PLUGIN
  providedCompile "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:$servletAPIVersion"
  runtime "javax.servlet:jstl:$jstlVersion"
}
```

Is this an eclipse plug-in problem or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also run into this problem long time ago. It really seems to be the problem related to the Eclipse plugin included in "Gradle IDE Pack" (as it works from the command line without problems).
My setup is probably way more complex than Yours (I'm including modules from one top-level gradle project into another top-level gradle project), but to overcome this specific error

```
Invalid classpath publish/ export dependency /my-project. Project entries not supported
```

... i excluded project dependency if some specific gradle property was missing:

```
if(project.hasProperty("myProjectRefAddedFromIDE")) {
    println "NB! Build script started with property 'myProjectRefAddedFromIDE' - expecting that this project in IDE is configured to add the direct reference to my-project"
} else {
    compile project(':my-project')
}
```

And to add the property "myProjectRefAddedFromIDE" only from IDE, i have configured eclipse plugin as follows:
Window -> Preferences -> Gradle -> Arguments -> Program arguments -> Use: ´-PmyProjectRefAddedFromIDE´

Just a warning: this will probably work for you, but there might be some other problem with Your setup, as for simple multi-module project (that doesn't include modules form another multi-module project) I don't have to use this workaround.

Comment: So what you're saying this is actually not going to work for eclipse projects. The solution would be to manually add projects as dependencies every time eclipse files updated. Right?

Answer (score 11):

Here's the magic steps I've discovered to make it work without messing with Project settings manually.

1. Run command: gradle cleanEclipse eclipse

   - as a result of this command Eclipse forgets that the project was supposed to have a gradle nature.
2. Add gradle nature back to the project by doing Configure -> Convert to Gradle Project.

   - as a result of this command the error reappears.
   - if incompatible plugin java version error appears then just delete .settings directory and refresh.
3. Run command: gradle cleanEclipseClasspath eclipseClasspath

   - this final step should get it fixed until the next time.

Comment: This works for me.  To be clear, this error marker always appears on the web project when I do a multi-project gradle import.  The error does not seem to cause any issues; it's just annoying to look at.

Comment: Another interesting find is that if you don't run cleanEclipse and just run eclipse task, then the G sign disappears from the project, but menu options for gradle projects remain visible and you can still do gradle related activities.

Comment: I simply ran the last step against the offending project and it worked for me. No reimport necessary.

Comment: Where (path) I need to excecute this command? In the eclipse root path?

Comment: You can execute from Eclipse if you have Gradle plugin installed. Just right click on the project, menu Gradle -> Tasks Quick Launcher.

Comment: If not, you can run gradle task from command line in the directory, where your build.gradle file is.

Comment: Last step is enough in most cases!

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this was due to mixing "faceted" and non-faceted projects. The projects with the error had been converted to faceted form, and the project they referenced which it was complaining about had not been. You can configure the project to be faceted via use of the `eclipse-wtp` plugin, by adding this to your ouat-contract gradle file:

```
eclipse{
    wtp{
        facet{}
    }
}
```

This will add facets for Java and a utility module when using the java and war plugins (see the [EclipseWTPFacet](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseWtpFacet.html) documentation for more information on the defaults and manually adding facets if you aren't using the war plug-in). The utility module part is the key to avoid the error.

Note that within this block you can also access the facet file directly to perform manual XML manipulation if you need to do other things, like specify a particular Apache Tomcat Runtime or or similar

Once you make this change, you can use Eclipse to do Gradle -> Refresh All on ouat-contract within your workspace - once I did this, the error went away

Comment: This worked for me.  Although a simpler solution (without changing any files manually) for me was to just make the dependent project a faceted Utility project.

Comment: @Marcus That will work, but the advantage to the file modification is that if the project is imported into another person's Eclipse, it will apply the faceting upon import instead of requiring another step and work out-of-box (it does a similar thing to the Eclipse files the faceted Utility setting does)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to remove the duplicate jar files from JRE System Library.
Steps Right click on Project and go to Build Path->configure build path->Libraries.
Remove the jars that are not in the classpath or duplicated in Maven dependency.